# Creating and Analysing sales potential Territories in Carto

Tags: carto

Is there any way to analyse territories and edit territories in Carto?

I do not need an algorithm to do it. I would need to aggregate polygons manually in order to create territories, see the results and keep tuning them until it makes sense.

I have polygons that represent neighbourhoods. Each polygon has data. Numbers of habitants, indexes, Number of companies, etc. I want to BE able to make/join polygons lets say to have 5 big areas. Each área should be identical so I must BE able to remove and add polygons to each area in order to understand if they are approximately similar.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are asking? What do you mean by "analysing"?

Comment: Hi. Sure. I have polygons that represent neighbourhoods. Each polygon has data. Numbers of habitants, indexes, Number of companies, etc. I want to BE able to make/join polygons lets say to have 5 big areas. Each área should be identical so I must BE able to remove and add polygons to each área in perder to understand ir they are approximatly similar.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide clarifications. Comments can drop out if neighbors are upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no out of the box solution in CARTO for applying the type of aggregation you are describing. But you can use any custom or already defined PostGIS function that achieves this goal. Furthermore, you could use any other (spatial) data science python library in combination [with CARTOframes](https://carto.com/developers/cartoframes/).